# Class with iter but not next

Tags: python, iterator, language-lawyer

For the iterator protocol you create both an `__iter__` and `__next__` method. However, what about the following case:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'James'
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
```

Now I can do:

```
>>> i=Item()
>>> iter(i)
<__main__.Item instance at 0x10bfe6e18>
```

But not:

```
>>> next(i)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: instance has no next() method
```

As far as I'm aware, the definition of iterator/iterable is:

- Iterable has the method `__iter__`
- Iterator has the method `__next__`

Would this then mean that my item above is an Iterable but not an Iterator? Or would it be neither because doing the following wouldn't work:

```
>>> for item in i:
...     print (item)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: instance has no next() method
```

Note this would be the full class that has the iterator methods defined:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'James'
        self.i = 0
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        if self.i >= len(self.name): raise StopIteration
        value = self.name[self.i]
        self.i += 1
        return value
```

Comment: What this class is is broken.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're mostly right with your definitions, but not quite.

- An object is *iterable* if it has an `__iter__` method that returns an iterator.
- An object is an *iterator* if it has a `__next__` method to get the next value while iterating. But iterators in Python are also expected to be iterable. They should all have an `__iter__` method that returns `self`.

Your first example has an `__iter__` method, but because it returns `self` and the object is not an iterator (since it has no `__next__` method), it's not really a valid iterable either.

To make a non-iterator iterable, you need to return *some other object* that is a valid iterator. One sneaky way to do it is to make `__iter__` a generator method (by using `yield` in its implementation). But if you have some sequence of values to return, you could also just return an iterator over that sequence.

The class in your last code block is indeed an iterator. But if you wanted to make it an iterable that is not its own iterator (perhaps because you want to be able to iterate over it several times), you would probably want something more like this:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'James'
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.name)
```

Answer (score 4):

`__iter__` and `__next__`, as iterable and iterator, are different things. And although it is possible to have both methods on the same class, with `__iter__` returning `self`, this would work only for proof of concepts, not for production code.

An iterable will have an `__iter__` method that returns an object that has  `__next__`. If both are the same instances as in

**this is just a demo, with faulty code**

```py
class Item:
   def __init__(self, data):
       self.data = data
   def __iter__(self):
       self.counter = 0
       return self
   def __next__(self):
       self.counter += 1
       if self.counter > len(self.data):
            raise StopIteration()
       return self.data[self.counter - 1]
```

This will work - but if you try to create two independent iterators on the same instance of Item, they won't work as desired - since both would share the same counter - the attribute `counter` in the instance.

It is rare however that one needs to implement `__next__`: if  `__iter__` is writen as a generator function, having a `yield` instead of returning  `self`, that will just work. Python will call `__next__` on the generator created automatically with each call to `__iter__`:

**this works**

```py
class Item:
   def __init__(self, data):
       self.data = data
   def __iter__(self):
       for item in self.data:
            yield item
```

As you can see, the correct way is "nextless" and much simpler, and can also be implemented, in this case, by returning an independent iterator for the data. (The yield implementation is needed if getting to each item requires some custom computation)

**this also works**

```py
class Item:
   def __init__(self, data):
       self.data = data
   def __iter__(self):
       return iter(self.data)
```

(on this case, Python will call `__next__` on the iterator created for `self.data`)

If you really want to implement `__next__`, the object with that method have to keep track of any counter or pointers needed to retrieve the next items, and that must be independent of the host instance. The most straightforward way to do that is to have a second class, related to your first one, and have `__iter__` return an instance of that instead:

**working "full" example**

```py
class Item:
   def __init__(self, data):
       self.data = data

   def __iter__(self):
       return ItemIterator(self)

class ItemIterator:
   def __init__(self, item):
      self.item = item
      self.counter = 0

   def __next__(self):
       self.counter += 1
       if self.counter > len(self.item.data):
            raise StopIteration()
       return self.item.data[self.counter - 1]
```

Comment: this is a really great explanation, thank you very much for this. I've tried with the `yield` approach and that is very cool. Why does that work, and for example, doing `return item` does not?

Answer (score 2):

> Would this then mean that my item above is an Iterable but not an Iterator?

No; to be iterable, the `__iter__` method should return an iterator. Yours doesn't.

According to the [glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) in the official Python docs:

> **Iterable**
>
> An object capable of returning its members one at a time. Examples of iterables include all sequence types (such as `list`, `str`, and `tuple`) and some non-sequence types like `dict`, file objects, and objects of any classes you define with an `__iter__()` method or with a `__getitem__()` method that implements Sequence semantics.
>
> Iterables can be used in a `for` loop and in many other places where a sequence is needed (`zip()`, `map()`, …).

Since your item is not *"capable of returning its members one at a time"*, and cannot *"be used in a `for` loop [or] other places where a sequence is needed"*, it is not iterable.

Note also that the `__next__` method is not sufficient to be an iterator; an iterator must also have an `__iter__` method [which returns itself](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__):

> Iterator objects also need to implement this method; they are required to return themselves.

Comment: I see, thank you for your thorough answer. So in other words, if I were to do `def __iter__(self): return iter(self.name)` then it would be an iterable, correct?

Comment: `>>> [i for i in Item()]; ['J', 'a', 'm', 'e', 's']`

Comment: If `self.name` is iterable, then yes, that would work.